# Как проверять наличие динамически добавленного класса в js?

Tags: javascript

При скролле страницы к каждой из секций динамически добавляется класс activе, а затем пропадает, Как можно проверять наличие классов у секций?

```
let section1 = document.querySelector('.header');

let section2 = document.querySelector('.cooperation')

console.log(section1.classList.contains('active')) // true
console.log(section2.classList.contains('active')) // false
```

У section2 есть класс active, но в консоле показывает false

Comment: Приведите [mcve] вместе с проблемным html-кодом

Comment: Значит на момент проверки класса у элемента таки не было. Либо элементов с классом `cooperation` несколько, а ты проверяешь только у первого.

Comment: Может по тому же условию, по которому они и добавляются. Или в случае, если это не ваш скрипт, плагин какой то, или т.п. можете посмотреть в сторону https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver